# rails validations in active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two model product and variant.

Product.rb => model.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :variants, dependent: :destroy
end
```

variant.rb => model

```
class Variant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  validates :product_id, presence: true
end
```

I want to validate product_id validation when admin create record from variant form, not when admin create record from product model using has_many relationship.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `validates_associated :product` did you try this only validate the association

Comment: has_many :variants, dependent: :destroy, validate: false